# How to push the same view controller instance more than once

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var scheduleButtoncontroller = (IntroController)Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("IntroController");
        var PriceButtonController = (PriceViewController)Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PriceViewController");


        ScheduleButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (NavController.TopViewController as IntroController == null)
                this.NavController.PushViewController(scheduleButtoncontroller, true);
            SidebarController.CloseMenu();

        };

        PriceButton.TouchUpInside += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (NavController.TopViewController as PriceViewController == null)
                this.NavController.PushViewController(PriceButtonController, true);
            SidebarController.CloseMenu();

        };
```

I used this to push the view controllers with the push of a button on a slide menu. When i navigate to the same view twice(for example i would press the price button and go to that screen, then navigate to a different screen pressing the schedule button, then i press the price button again and it get an error), i get an exception

Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: I can't see where are you Push Same ViewController twice ??

Comment: when i navigate to a view controller1, then navigate away from it, and then navigate to the  viewcontroller1 again, i get the exception

Comment: why you want to push the same controller ? to show the controller you just use "SidebarController.ChangeContentView(new OtherContentController());"